# Adding Places Autocomplete in Alert Dialog

Tags: java, android, google-places-api, google-api-client

I have tried to use the code provided by Google in github. It is not working for some reason. It would be a great help if I could know where I have been wrong. I'm posting my code here. 
I'm not getting any errors but the autocomplete suggestion won't show up.
I have the google api key added. The connection callback shows that the google api client is connected.

MainActivity.Java

```
package com.example.sid.organizer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePrediction;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks{
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(mGoogleApiClient != null){
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

private PlaceAutocompleteAdapter mAdapter;

private AutoCompleteTextView mAutocompleteView;

private TextView mPlaceDetailsText;
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private TextView mPlaceDetailsAttribution;
private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_USA = new LatLngBounds(
        new LatLng(32.6393,-117.004304), new LatLng(44.901184 ,-67.32254));


/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */

private ViewPager mViewPager;
EditText add_alert_name;
ListView alert_list;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
//        if(this.mGoogleApiClient == null){
//            Toast.makeText(this, "Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//        }else{
//            Toast.makeText(this, "Not null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//        }

    alert_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.alerts_list);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
                final View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_alert, null, false);
                alert_builder.setView(v);
                alert_builder.setTitle("Add Alert");
                alert_builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
//                        Get texts from the alerts
//                        Validate
//                        Add to local storage
                            add_alert_name = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.add_alert_name);
                            mAutocompleteView = (AutoCompleteTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_places);
                            String add_al_name = add_alert_name.getText().toString();
                            String add_al_loc = mAutocompleteView.getText().toString();
                            if(mAutocompleteView != null){
                                mAutocompleteView.setOnItemClickListener(mAutocompleteClickListener);
                                mPlaceDetailsText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.place_details);
                                mPlaceDetailsAttribution = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.place_attribution);
                                // Set up the adapter that will retrieve suggestions from the Places Geo Data API that cover
                                // the entire world.
                                mAdapter = new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(v.getContext(), mGoogleApiClient, BOUNDS_USA,
                                        null);
                                mAutocompleteView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Auto is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            if(add_al_name != null || add_al_name != "" || add_al_loc != null || add_al_loc != ""){
                                new Alerts().AddAlert(add_al_name,add_al_loc);
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Incorrect Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                });
                alert_builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                alert_builder.show();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });



}
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mAutocompleteClickListener
        = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        /*
         Retrieve the place ID of the selected item from the Adapter.
         The adapter stores each Place suggestion in a AutocompletePrediction from which we
         read the place ID and title.
          */
        final AutocompletePrediction item = mAdapter.getItem(position);
        final String placeId = item.getPlaceId();
        final CharSequence primaryText = item.getPrimaryText(null);

        Log.i(TAG, "Autocomplete item selected: " + primaryText);

        /*
         Issue a request to the Places Geo Data API to retrieve a Place object with additional
         details about the place.
          */
        PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
        placeResult.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked: " + primaryText,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(TAG, "Called getPlaceById to get Place details for " + placeId);
    }
};
/**
 * Callback for results from a Places Geo Data API query that shows the first place result in
 * the details view on screen.
 */
private ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer> mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback
        = new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
        if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            // Request did not complete successfully
            Log.e(TAG, "Place query did not complete. Error: " + places.getStatus().toString());
            places.release();
            return;
        }
        // Get the Place object from the buffer.
        final Place place = places.get(0);

        // Format details of the place for display and show it in a TextView.
        mPlaceDetailsText.setText(formatPlaceDetails(getResources(), place.getName(),
                place.getId(), place.getAddress(), place.getPhoneNumber(),
                place.getWebsiteUri()));

        // Display the third party attributions if set.
        final CharSequence thirdPartyAttribution = places.getAttributions();
        if (thirdPartyAttribution == null) {
            mPlaceDetailsAttribution.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            mPlaceDetailsAttribution.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mPlaceDetailsAttribution.setText(Html.fromHtml(thirdPartyAttribution.toString()));
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "Place details received: " + place.getName());

        places.release();
    }
};

private static Spanned formatPlaceDetails(Resources res, CharSequence name, String id,
                                          CharSequence address, CharSequence phoneNumber, Uri websiteUri) {
    Log.e(TAG, res.getString(R.string.place_details, name, id, address, phoneNumber,
            websiteUri));
    return Html.fromHtml(res.getString(R.string.place_details, name, id, address, phoneNumber,
            websiteUri));

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
            + connectionResult.getErrorCode());

    // TODO(Developer): Check error code and notify the user of error state and resolution.
    Toast.makeText(this,
            "Could not connect to Google API Client: Error " + connectionResult.getErrorCode(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connection Suspended", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                Alerts alerts = new Alerts();
                return alerts;
            case 1:
                Deals deals = new Deals();
                return deals;
            case 2:
                NearBy nearBy = new NearBy();
                return nearBy;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "ALERTS";
            case 1:
                return "DEALS";
            case 2:
                return "NEAR BY";
        }
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
  //        dialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

PlaceAutocompleteAdapter.java

```
package com.example.sid.organizer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.annotation.LayoutRes;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.text.style.CharacterStyle;
import android.text.style.StyleSpan;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataBufferUtils;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePrediction;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePredictionBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static android.R.attr.resource;

public class PlaceAutocompleteAdapter
        extends ArrayAdapter<AutocompletePrediction> implements Filterable {

private static final String TAG = "PlaceAutocompleteAdapter";
private static final CharacterStyle STYLE_BOLD = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
/**
 * Current results returned by this adapter.
 */
private ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> mResultList;

/**
 * Handles autocomplete requests.
 */
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

/**
 * The bounds used for Places Geo Data autocomplete API requests.
 */
private LatLngBounds mBounds;

/**
 * The autocomplete filter used to restrict queries to a specific set of place types.
 */
private AutocompleteFilter mPlaceFilter;

/**
 * Initializes with a resource for text rows and autocomplete query bounds.
 *
 * @see android.widget.ArrayAdapter#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int)
 */
public PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, GoogleApiClient googleApiClient,
                                LatLngBounds bounds, AutocompleteFilter filter) {
    super(context, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1);
    mGoogleApiClient = googleApiClient;
    mBounds = bounds;
    mPlaceFilter = filter;
}

/**
 * Sets the bounds for all subsequent queries.
 */
public void setBounds(LatLngBounds bounds) {
    mBounds = bounds;
}

/**
 * Returns the number of results received in the last autocomplete query.
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mResultList.size();
}

/**
 * Returns an item from the last autocomplete query.
 */
@Override
public AutocompletePrediction getItem(int position) {
    return mResultList.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    // Sets the primary and secondary text for a row.
    // Note that getPrimaryText() and getSecondaryText() return a CharSequence that may contain
    // styling based on the given CharacterStyle.

    AutocompletePrediction item = getItem(position);

    TextView textView1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    TextView textView2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
    textView1.setText(item.getPrimaryText(STYLE_BOLD));
    textView2.setText(item.getSecondaryText(STYLE_BOLD));

    return row;
}

/**
 * Returns the filter for the current set of autocomplete results.
 */
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            // We need a separate list to store the results, since
            // this is run asynchronously.
            ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> filterData = new ArrayList<>();

            // Skip the autocomplete query if no constraints are given.
            if (constraint != null) {
                // Query the autocomplete API for the (constraint) search string.
                filterData = getAutocomplete(constraint);
            }

            results.values = filterData;
            if (filterData != null) {
                results.count = filterData.size();
            } else {
                results.count = 0;
            }

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                // The API returned at least one result, update the data.
                mResultList = (ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                // The API did not return any results, invalidate the data set.
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
            // Override this method to display a readable result in the AutocompleteTextView
            // when clicked.
            if (resultValue instanceof AutocompletePrediction) {
                return ((AutocompletePrediction) resultValue).getFullText(null);
            } else {
                return super.convertResultToString(resultValue);
            }
        }
    };
}

/**
 * Submits an autocomplete query to the Places Geo Data Autocomplete API.
 * Results are returned as frozen AutocompletePrediction objects, ready to be cached.
 * objects to store the Place ID and description that the API returns.
 * Returns an empty list if no results were found.
 * Returns null if the API client is not available or the query did not complete
 * successfully.
 * This method MUST be called off the main UI thread, as it will block until data is returned
 * from the API, which may include a network request.
 *
 * @param constraint Autocomplete query string
 * @return Results from the autocomplete API or null if the query was not successful.
 * @see Places#GEO_DATA_API#getAutocomplete(CharSequence)
 * @see AutocompletePrediction#freeze()
 */
private ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> getAutocomplete(CharSequence constraint) {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting autocomplete query for: " + constraint);

        // Submit the query to the autocomplete API and retrieve a PendingResult that will
        // contain the results when the query completes.
        PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results =
                Places.GeoDataApi
                        .getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, constraint.toString(),
                                mBounds, mPlaceFilter);

        // This method should have been called off the main UI thread. Block and wait for at most 60s
        // for a result from the API.
        AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictions = results
                .await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // Confirm that the query completed successfully, otherwise return null
        final Status status = autocompletePredictions.getStatus();
        if (!status.isSuccess()) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error contacting API: " + status.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e(TAG, "Error getting autocomplete prediction API call: " + status.toString());
            autocompletePredictions.release();
            return null;
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "Query completed. Received " + autocompletePredictions.getCount()
                + " predictions.");

        // Freeze the results immutable representation that can be stored safely.
        return DataBufferUtils.freezeAndClose(autocompletePredictions);
    }
    Log.e(TAG, "Google API client is not connected for autocomplete query.");
    return null;
}
}
```

Thank you